# How to change bundle id in new iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to change to a different bundle id in iTunes Connect but i can't find a way to do it in the new interface introduced by Apple. Also, i can't find the SKU information of my app like in the old iTunes website. My app is still not submitted for review. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to iTunes Connect
2. Select your app
3. Click on **More**
4. Click on **About This App**
5. Change your bundle ID
6. Click on **Save**

Comment: Did not work for me. App has never been uploaded, but "About This App" box is not editable.

Comment: Looks like they've changed the UI, now there is a dropdown select you can use to pick one of your registered bundle IDs.

Comment: You can change Bundle ID only IF YOU STILL NOT UPLOADED FIRST BUILD YET

Answer (score 14):

I also have the same issue, and have been able to edit this field in past apps. I called Apple support and they said that the issue is; that once Game Centre is turned on for a BundleID it becomes non editable. We even tried turning Game Centre off but to no avail. They told me the options were to use change the BundleID back in Xcode to match the BundleID in iTunesConnect or to change the name of my game in iTunesConnect (to free up that name) and then create a new app/game in iTunesConnect with the newly freed up name and now proper BundleID.

It should be noted that if you change the name to free it up and create a new app/game, you will not be able to delete the old game/app from your iTunesConnect. It will just sit there in limbo.

They said that there is NO way to edit this field once it has been marked is not editable.

This doesn't answer the issue on how to change it but may make it so people stop spending hours trying to change their BundleID.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Connect > Your App > More > About This App

You may need to change the Bundle ID dropdown to Wildcard which makes the Bundle ID Suffix will be editable.  You can put the full Bundle ID in there: i.e. “com.companyname.appbundleid"

Answer (score 1):

To refine on all of these great answers

iTunes connect -> Your app -> on the left side panel App information and under General information you can locate the bundle ID drop down menu and select a different id and then save your changes.

Don't forget to add the new id to Apple developer portal 1st.